# HTML/CSS: How to make a <div> containing an <img> tag inside a <section> responsive?

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

I'm making a website using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), On the second page (or equivalently, second section) I want to achieve a very simple layout where I have a header fixed on top of the page displaying an image which should be responsive, or decreases in size as the window shrinks but stays at the top.

Currently, I'm wrapping the image to be displayed in a `div`. I then scale the `div` fullscreen using,

```
.post-header {
  background: #22BDA0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

The `img` tag inside of the `div` has a class `header-image` which I style as,

```
.post-header .header-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
```

However, I'm not getting the desired result. There is a small space on top of the second page which I can't get rid of. You can see the website I'm making along with the source code [HERE.](https://javeria2.github.io/) Just scroll down to second page, or click `Personal Details` on the homepage.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: don't see any img in your source code on section 2

Comment: Hey, I made the commits not a long while ago, could you refresh the page? it should be there, I see it. Just hit the link here [link](https://javeria2.github.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you just give `height:100%;` to `.section2-container`? Will it solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the issue of extra space on the top. However, on setting the height of the `div` and the `img` as `auto`. I have lost control on how it looks in full screen. It looks too big for my liking and I want to set it to  a specific height. However, when I set a fixed heigh using `em` or `%`, I loose the responsiveness. In other words, the height of the `div` or the `img` no longer auto-scales with the size of the window. Any workaround to this?

Comment: What if you just set a specific height to a div, remove the img tag and use the image on a background? You can use background-size: cover; to make sure it always fills the div.

Comment: I could do that yes, in fact I just did. However, now I loose control over positioning the image to my desired place. I've committed the changes to my website. Can you have a look and see what I'm talking about? [SEE HERE](https://javeria2.github.io) , I want the image to be a lot smaller than what it is currently.

Comment: You can play with background styles. For example, you can have something like this:
background-size: 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've made a lot of progress. However, after playing around a little I got the position of the image and the header to be exactly what I want. Except the fact that it's not responsive. When I reduce the window size, the edges get cut-off of the background image. You can see the updates as you said [here](https://javeria2.github.io/). How do I now automatically reduce the height of the `div` such that the background stays where it is and I don't loose the edges either?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: table-cell;` from `.fp-tableCell` and the padding disappears. Does this need to have display set to table-cell?

fullPage.js has an option: `verticalCentered` that can be set to false. This seems like a good solution, since the alternative means always trying to ensure that the content of the containing element is always 100%.

Comment: `.fp-tableCell` is defined in `fullPage.css`, I'm just using it as-is with some overrides in the css I wrote.

Comment: Ah, I see what they're doing - they use `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` because everything is supposed to be centered vertically using their plugin. Set `verticalCentered: false` in the jQuery initialization, see if that works.